# What am I doing wrong? I am very new to python

Tags: python

I am trying to run this

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame() #empty dataframe

for csv_file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    csv_file_name = csv_file.split('\\')[7]
    print('Processing File : {}'.format(csv_file_name))
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
    df.set_index(['TIMESTAMP'], inplace=True)

    if 'Unnamed:13' in df.columns:
        df.drop(['Unnamed:13'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    df_trim = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)

    new_df = df_trim[df_trim['SERIES'].isin(['EQ', 'BE', 'SM'])]
    final_df = final_df.append(new_df)

final_df.sort_index(inplace=True) #to sort by dates
```

========================================

Getting error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 5
      3 for csv_file in file_list:
      4     df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
----> 5     csv_file_name = csv_file.split('\\')[7]
      6     print('Processing File : {}'.format(csv_file_name))
      7     df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing worng? what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you split the string into array, you want to get element out of array range. So, the solution can be (if you want to extract last item):

```
csv_file_name = csv_file.split('\\')[len(csv_file.split('\\'))-1]
```

Comment: THank you so mcuh.... the insight helps... this worked.

Comment: `len(...)` is irrelevant here `csv_file.split('\\')[-1]` will return the last element

Answer (score 1):

`csv_file_name = csv_file.split('\\')[7]`

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Means that the list `csv_file.split('\\')` has less than 7 items, so 7 is out of the range of indexes

`csv_file.split('\\')` turns an array into a list, broken up by the delimiter `\`, so `this\is\a\string` turns into `['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']`. If this list has less than 7 items, there must be less than 7 `\`s in the string,

Comment: What is this used for as in when it says 7 what is this referring to ? 

Like are there less than 7 CSV files in the folder where i am trying to run this? 
less than seven columns ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the 8th elements (7 + 1, as list starts at index 0 in python) of the list `csv_file.split('\\')`

Based on the error, this list does not have 8 elements (`IndexError: list index out of range`).

If I were you, I would try to see what `csv_file.split('\\')` looks like either :

- by adding a breakpoint and checking with a debugger
- by adding a `print(csv_file.split('\\'))` before the actual error)

Answer (score 1):

`IndexError: list index out of range`

This error means you are trying to reach a section of an array that does not exist. e.g.

some_array  = [ "a", "b", "c" ]

`len(some_array)` will show 3, but as arrays are 0 based that means the last element  `some_array[2]` is "c"

In your case you have split `csv_file` which I can only assume is a full path to a file. e.g. `/my/path/to/some/file.txt`.
The problem is you have asked for the hard coded 7th item `csv_file.split('\\')[7]`. Hardcoding is VERY bad practice because it is fragile. For one of the paths there are less than 7 elements, hence your error. You could get the length of the array, or use `[-1]` to get the last element.

However if all you want is the filename then there are much better python functions to get it. e.g.

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(your_path))
```

Comment: Upvoted because I believe `os.path.basename()` is what the OP wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `-1` index will return the last element, in your case the file name.

Although in Linux the path strings follows forward slashes `/` so its better to use `os.path.basename` to get the file name.

```py
import os
print(os.path.basename(csv_file))
```

```
>>> 'file_name.file_extension'
```